# firestore cant add data

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add collectionViewData into firestore, but code below doesn't work, I tried to search up answer, but there is no answer anywhere on internet, any solutions ?

```
let userId = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!
db.collection("users").document(userId).setData([
  "countryImage": "asd",
  "countryName": self.countryName.text!
])
```

my firestore (sorry for the link I'm new here):

[image: firestore image link]

Comment: The current code seems to be adding data in user's document and not in the saved cells sub-collection. Where are you trying to add data?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I'm trying to add data in savedcells sub-collection

Comment: As pointed out by Dharmaraj, your code and screenshot are telling two slightly different versions of the story. If you are trying to add under the savedCells collection you would need to go with something like this: db.collection("users").document(userId).collection('savedCells').setData(). Furthermore I would also look at the security rules to make sure you are not trying to write to a collection that your client does not have permissions to write to. Lastly, use "add" rather than "set" if you don't intend to generate IDs yourself.

Comment: @Stf_F thank you for the comment, what did you mean by "collection that your client does not have permissions to write to"

Comment: If you use the client SDK (not Admin) you need to check that your security rules are updated to allow the writes to your sub/collection(s).

Comment: @Stf_F unfortunately, none of your solutions work for me.

Comment: @Stf_F with add() my console returns an error `[Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] AppCheck failed: 'The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.devicecheck.error error 0.)'`

Comment: @balaketbula do u get any error response?

Comment: @udi the only error I get is in console and I wrote that above in my last comment, please check

Comment: @balaketbula if you a using a simulator try using a real device else check device time is correct.

Comment: As mentioned above, the code in your question has nothing to do with the screenshot that's included - the data from that function will be written to the path `/users/uid/` where `users` is a collection and `uid` is a document that will then have two fields `countryImage` and `countryName`. You're screenshot includes a path to `savedCells` which is not included in the code. Can you either update the code or screenshot so they match? The comment about *permission to write* was in regards to [Firebase Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview)